# Can create / edit groups file but can't change permission

Tags: linux, permissions, sftp

my scenario is:

2 users : firstUser and  secondUser in developers group.

This user connect to server with sftp;

if firstUser  create a file, this file was 775 , ownered by firstUser, group developers;

with secondUser i can edit and write this file but if i try:

```
 chmod 777 testfile.txt
```

I can't do that!

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide the results of 'ls -l testfile.txt'.  There are two ways you can try to resolve this.  I am unsure if they would be the best approach but here they are.  Add a sudo prior to the chmod, e.g., 'sudo chmod 777 testfile.txt' and supply the root password.  Or you could change the owner, e.g., 'chown secondUser:developersgroup testfile.txt' then chmod.

Comment: -rwxrwxr-x 1 firstUser developers 0 nov 15 16:41

Comment: secondUser can **delete** this file but can't change permissions

Comment: Yes, then either use sudo prior to the command and use the root password, or change the owner, "chown secondUser:developers testfile.txt" then use "chmod 777 testfile.txt".

Answer (score 0):

only root or the owner can do that.